# Can the product of a nonzero principal ideal and a non-principal ideal become a principal ideal in a ring of algebraic integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a number field and $\mathcal O_F$ be its ring of algebraic integers.

Let $(a)$ be a nonzero principal ideal in $\mathcal O_F$ and $I$ be a nonprincipal ideal in $\mathcal O_F$. Note they are just **ordinary** ideals (ideals that are literally contained in $\mathcal O_F$), not fractional ideals. I wonder if the product $(a)I$ is necessarily non-principal.

More generally one could ask if $IJ$ is a principal ideal in $\mathcal O_F$ then $I$ and $J$ are both principal.

---

If this is true then I guess this might be true in a more general setting (integral domain ?), so please feel free to point it out if so.

Comment: If $(a)I=(b)$ then $I=(b/a)$. On the other hand, $IJ$ can easily be principal even when $I$ and $J$ are not - just their classes (in the ideal class group) must be inverse to each other. E.g. $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$, $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2=(2)$.

Comment: @user8268 As I said, I assumed that they are ordinary ideals instead of fractional ideals... so the inverse of $a$ in $F$ may not lie in $\mathcal O_F$.

Comment: but $b/a$ is there.

Comment: @user8268 why? $a$ may not be a unit in the ring of integers.

Comment: because: $(a)I=(b)$, so $b\in(a)I$, so $b=ac$ for some $c\in I$, so $b/a=c\in I\subset O_F$ (and yes, sorry, I was supposing $a\neq 0$)

Comment: @user8268 Still you are not proving $I=(c)$? I think you just proved $I\supset (c)$...

Comment: I think I'll let you work it out now

Comment: @NoOne $4 \in \Bbb Z$, $\frac{1}{2} \notin \Bbb Z$, but $\frac{4}{2} \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: By definition “ordinary” ideals are fractional ideals...